# Rename values in r kable

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

Let's take the iris dataset as an example.

```
dat <- iris[1:10, ]
dat[, 1:4] <- round(dat[ ,1:4])
```

As you can see, the first four columns contain numerical values and the final column contains character values.

Now, when creating a kable table, I would like to rename the values so that the first column contains character values (0 becomes "Zero", 2 becomes "Two", etc.), the second to forth columns remain the same (i.e. numerical) and the values in the final column starts with a capital letter ("Setosa"). Is it possible to achieve this using the kableExtra package? I would prefer if I didn't have to recode the values inside the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with different packages. I hope this is what you are looking for.
First manipulate the data with different packages then create kable table

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(xfun) # numbers_to_words function

# your data
dat <- iris[1:10, ]
dat[, 1:4] <- round(dat[ ,1:4])

# create kable table
dat1 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = numbers_to_words(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  mutate(Species = str_to_title(Species)) %>% # from stringr package in tidyverse
  kbl() %>%
  kable_styling()
dat1 # call table
```

[image]